# Placing a byte at a very specific address on a hard disk, can it be done? (using c++ for example)

Tags: c++, filesystems, hex, offset

This might sound silly, but I'd like to know how to do the following.

I've created a .txt file. The content of the .txt file is the word "hi" without the quotes. So the .txt file contains 2 characters. When opening the .txt file in a hex-editor one sees 2 hexadecimal pairs, namely "68" and "69":

```
Offset
00000000 68 69 hi
```

What I want to do is the following. I want to take the "69" hex-pair and put it at a very specific address on the hard disk. So basically I want to take a byte and place it at a very specific address on the hard disk.

So "68" should be at address **n** and "69" should be at address **n+1000000**.

Now this is the silly part, after having done this I want my .txt file to still be 2 bytes large and I still want to be able to open my .txt file in Notepad and see the word "hi".
How can I do this?

Comment: This is likely to be very operating system and file system specific.  Perhaps you could tell us which OS and FS are of interest to you and people can try to answer.   There is almost certainly no platform-agnostic way of achieving this.  In most cases it will be impossible. Furthermore, a filesystem is a projection of possibly non-sequential disk blocks. Is the location within the filesystem important, or the location on the hard drive itself? If so, offset from the start of the partition or from the start of the disk? What do you want the behaviour to be if there is already data there?

Comment: Tell us what your ultimate goal is and we can help further. If this is just academic, then you should probably say so. This is a great way to destroy your file system

Comment: It's for academic purposes. Mainly to get a better understanding of how to do this.

The OS and file system I'm targeting is Windows + NTFS, however it would be nice if there was a way to do this cross-platform and cross file system, although that might be too much to ask, but if there is a way to do that I'll gladly hear it.

My first goal is to know how to do this for Windows and NTFS and to do it safely, without messing up the hard disk and the data on it.

Comment: Also, does it have to be a hard disc? Could it be flash memory instead?

Comment: Well I'd like to to know how to do this on a hard disk/drive and was hoping the method would extend(be the same) to flash memory, but from your question I perceive that separate methods might need to be used. Or could the same method work on flash memory too as long as it uses the same file system as the hard disk?

Comment: You will not be able to write arbitrary adresses without danger of messing up your filesystem.

Comment: What if I would first reserve a part of the free space of the hard disk and protect it. For example by creating some sort of sand box.

I have no idea how to do that, but a concrete solution might be to appoint several free blocks on the hard disk for testing purposes.

Could that work?

Comment: @TyTN:  Also, you're putting very specific requirements in, and they aren't entirely clear.  What do you mean by position n and position n + 1000000?  I wasn't aware that byte positions were numbered on a hard disk.  If they're positions in a file, the file is going to be more than 2 bytes long.

Comment: @David Thornley:

I really do mean addresses on a hard disk. Like you said:"If they're positions in a file, the file is going to be more than 2 bytes long."


But just out of curiosity. Does a method exist to place 2 characters in a .txt file 1000000 positions apart from each other while maintaining a 2-byte file size? If so, that would do too, but I fear that such a method does not exist.

Comment: Are you trying to perform Steganography(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) with plain text files? If you are, there are easier ways.

Answer (score 2):

Not happening.

No filesystem will let you assign byte locations for bytes on the same sector (usu. 512 bytes).

Almost no filesystem will allow you to assign byte locations that are not aligned to sectors.

Most filesystems use larger sizes of allocation units (typically 4096 bytes).

Comment: Theoretically, you could read the entire sector and replace it with the exact same sector with two bytes changed. You would need the ability to read and write sectors at will. Unless you program drivers, this is unlikely to happen. Perhaps someone who writes disc defrag utilities might know more.

Comment: @Joshua's answer:

But then how do operating systems fragment files and how do defragmentation applications create contiguous files from fragmented files on a disk? Perhaps the way those applications work is a way to do what I intend, albeit perhaps in a slightly different way. 

Software that manages fragmentation surely needs to be able to place parts of a file at specific address locations and move them around or make files contiguous again, right?

Perhaps inspiration can be gained from that type of software.

Comment: Software that handles disk defragmentaion moves things around at the block level. Its normally an offline operation but various online implementations have been built.

Comment: FYI, a two byte file cannot be fragmented.

Comment: @Andres: on Windows: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 for the first hard disk

Comment: Would it be possible to change the offset of the second byte to for example 17233? I know offsets are relative memory addresses, but perhaps messing with those would make it possible. So then one would have the first byte located in a sector at offset 00000000 and the second byte would have an offset of 00017233. All within one sector/block while maintaining the 2-byte file size. However I fear this would only be possible if offsets were somehow stored somewhere, rather than calculated relatively from the first offset 00000000.

Comment: @TyTN:  You mentioned "a way to do what I intend".  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  What would be the use of being able to put bytes in an arbitrary position on a hard disk?

Comment: @David Thornley: For clarification see my reply to TheUndeadFish's answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do pretty much goes against everything that modern operating systems and file systems try to take care of. The literal location and layout of data on the disk are purposefully abstracted away.

Somewhere somehow there is probably a way to get low level access to the file system. And in theory you might be able to place the first byte of your file in one sector and then the second byte of your file in a different section. But this makes the assumption that the file system supports that first sector being partially filled without the file being ended there. And this also assumes that no utility or such ever comes along and compacts that data together.

Generally speaking, there's no reason to ever want to do such a thing in the first place. The only reason I can imagine is that you're wanting to hide data in between those two bytes. Like writing 1000000 bytes (or how ever many) to the literal disk, but then make the OS believe that only the first and last bytes actually exists in the file. So then anyone who views the file through normal means will never see the 999998 bytes in the middle. Presumably, only your specially written program would know how to get at them.

If that is really your goal, then there might or might not be a way to do it. I don't have any other specific advice in that regard. However, you might want to research into something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) and how it is able to make a hidden encrypted partition on a disk.

Comment: The goal is not to hide data, but rather to use the address of the second byte as a third byte. That way I could store 3 bytes in a 2-byte file. But in order to assign specific data to the "third byte" one would need to place that byte at a very specific address.

Perhaps there is a more sensible way of storing 3 bytes in 2 bytes, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @TyTN:  There is no general way of storing 3 bytes in 2 bytes.  If the second bytes is not right after the first one, you need to record where it is somehow, and that's extra storage.

Comment: @TyTN: Most (all?) modern file systems are going to be optimized for storing larger files. Hence the whole concept of sectors. So any file under the sector size will take up one whole sector regardless. As such trying to "compress" 3 bytes of data into a 2 byte file is would not only be useless but also subject to many practical problems. In addition to the file system not letting you put bytes where you want, how would this scheme ever deal with two files having the same third byte?

Comment: *"In addition to the file system not letting you put bytes where you want, how would this scheme ever deal with two files having the same third byte?"*

That's a good point.